# How to get the serving host and port in python pyramid application?

Tags: python, settings, pyramid

I am trying to get the serving host and port of a pyramid applications using:

```
settings = get_current_registry().settings
```

But how can I get the host?

I tried:

```
settings.get('host')
```

But I am getting `None`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Pyramid could be running in a WSGI server that is hosted on multiple addresses and ports; this is not something that Pyramid configuration can see. Use the request object information to see what address the browser contacted for each request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
request.host or request.host_url
```

[pyramid.request](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request)

Answer (score 0):

By default python pyramid use **pserve** and you can run pyramid by using **mod_wsgi** and **uwsgi**

Pyramid serving host and port exist in development.ini and production.ini file

*For pserve:*

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543
```

*For Uwsgi:*

```
[uwsgi]
http = :9090
paste = config:project_url/test/development.ini**(set your directory)**
master = true
processes = 4
threads = 2
```

you can change this port

running command:

```
pserve development.ini
uwsgi development.ini
```